# Multiple abstract views - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am building a project with `ionic` where there are different views handled by `ui-router`, that needs be nested together. This is the part of the code where the `states` of the `ui-view` are handled:

```
$stateProvider

// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('filters', {
  url: '/filters',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/filters.html'
})

// and one for the search bar
.state('search', {
  url: '/search',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
})

// Each tab has its own nav history stack:
.state('filters.search.locations', {
  url: '/locations',
  views: {
    'tab-locations': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-locations.html',
      controller: 'LocationsCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('filters.search.job-categories', {
  url: '/job-categories',
  views: {
    'tab-job-categories': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-job-categories.html',
      controller: 'JobCategoriesCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('filters.search.levels', {
  url: '/levels',
  views: {
    'tab-levels': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-levels.html',
      controller: 'LevelsCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

As you can see, my intention is to combine the states `filters` & `search` and display them together, but apparently I am doing something wrong. Do you know what is the issue with my code?

Thanks in advance for your replies!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
  $stateProvider

    .state('filters', {
      url: '/filters',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/filters.html'
    })

    // note this ...
    .state('filters.search', {
      url: '/search',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
    })

    .state('filters.search.locations', {
      url: '/locations',
      views: {
        'tab-locations': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-locations.html',
          controller: 'LocationsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

    //and so on ...
```