# Multiple abstract views does not work - Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

I have done this project with ionic where there are multiple abstract views one inside another. But it does not work, although I do it exactly like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147512/multiple-abstract-views-ionic)

```
angular_app = angular.module 'starter'

angular_app.config ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider)->
  $stateProvider
  .state 'tab',{
    url : '/tab'
    abstract : true
    templateUrl : 'templates/tabs.html'
  }
  .state 'tab.home',{
    url : '/home'
    views : {
      'tab-home' : {
        templateUrl : 'templates/home.html'
      }
    }
  }
  .state 'tab.searcher',{
    url : '/searcher'
    abstract : true
    templateUrl : 'templates/template-searcher.html'
  }
  .state 'tab.searcher.ingredients',{
    url : '/ingredients'
    views : {
      'tab-ingredients' : {
        templateUrl : 'templates/ingredients-searcher.html'
      }
    }
  }
  return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the tab.home definition we can infer that in tab there must be a named `tab-home` ui-view. tab.searcher is a child of tab with it's own template, but it is *not* inserted in the named ui-view.

I added a snippet where I mimic your state configuration and make the minimal changes, which I assume must be logically given to make sense (named ui-views in templates, and views definitions in state objects).

Please have a look, and let me know if there are other issues.

```js
angular.module('TestApp', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        template: '<div ui-view="tab-home"></div>'
      })
      .state('tab.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
          'tab-home': {template: 'Tab Home'}
        }
      })
      .state('tab.searcher', {
        url: '/searcher',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
          'tab-home': {
            template: 'Tab Searcher <div ui-view="tab-ingredients"></div>'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('tab.searcher.ingredients', {
        url: '/ingredients',
        views: {
          'tab-ingredients': {template: 'Ingredients!'}
        }
      });

    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/searcher/ingredients");
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.12/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-ui-router@0.3.1/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Note that it is also possible to directly define which named ui-view should render the template.
E.g.: Set template for the named ui-view *root* in state *a*. Set template for the named ui-view *nav* in *b*

```
.state('a.b.c', {
   // ...
   views: {
      'root@a': {template:'Foo'},
      'nav@b': {template:'Bar'}
   }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is a `tab-home` view on `tab`, because the home tab is a child of the tab state, but it is not its only possible view

Comment: Maybe it will be a "nice" solution if we could have multiple templateUrls on the same view, but i don't now if it is possible

Comment: `ui-view="tab-home"` is a *named* view in the tab state. Children of the tab state may specify a template for this *ui-view*. Like I mentioned under the snippet, it is possible to have multiple named views. You can find more info here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views